# Inserting new table row with different column number with Apache poi

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a Word table with 1 row and 2 columns, and I want to insert a new row with 3 columns using Apache poi with Java. What I want to achieve is this:

[image: picture_1]

But what I get is this:

[image: picture_2]

I have searched the Internet for a solution but all I get was about setting column width which does not work for my case. Could anyone help me with this problem?

This is my code which I took from one of the examples in Stack Overflow to work around that yield the output shown in second picture:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\testdoc.docx");
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    XWPFTable table = doc.getTableArray(0);
    XWPFTableRow oldRow = table.getRow(0);
    table.insertNewTableRow(1);
    XWPFTableRow newRow = table.getRow(1);

    int indWidth = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < oldRow.getTableCells().size(); i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        BigInteger width = oldRow.getCell(i).getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().getW();
        sum += width.intValue();

        indWidth = sum/oldRow.getTableCells().size();
    }

    XWPFTableCell cell;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cell = newRow.createCell();

        CTTcPr ctTcPr = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();

        CTTblWidth cellWidth = ctTcPr.addNewTcW();
        cellWidth.setType(oldRow.getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcW().getType());  // sets type of width
        BigInteger width = BigInteger.valueOf(indWidth);
        cellWidth.setW(width);  // sets width

        if (oldRow.getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan() != null) {
            ctTcPr.setGridSpan(oldRow.getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().getGridSpan()); // sets grid span if any
        }

        XWPFRun run = cell.getParagraphs().get(0).createRun();
        run.setText("NewRow C" + i); 
    }

    doc.write(out);
    doc.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a solution, for the java world, but not with poi...

With pxDoc ([www.pxdoc.fr](http://www.pxdoc.fr), disclaimer: I am one of its authors...), this can be perfectly achieved with the following code :

```
document {
    table {
        row {
            cell { "Column 1" }
            cell { "Column 2" }
        }
        row {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                cell {
                    "NewRow C" + i
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```